# What does the word 「ありゃしねえ」mean?

Tags: expressions, particle-は, negation, contractions, renyōkei

It is a situation which a salesperson announces to a group of people to attract them to buy his goods.

Here is the full sentence.

こんなお買【か】いどくはどこの世【せ】界【かい】へいったって **ありゃしねえ**よ

Comment: 〜ねえ is a colloquial form of 〜ない, so it probably is [ありゃしない](http://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%82%E3%82%8A%E3%82%83%E3%81%97%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can add focus particles like は or も to verbs, but in order to do so, you have to split the verb into two parts so that the particle has some place to go.  We'll split the verb into its continuative stem (called 連用形 in Japanese) and the verb する.

For example:

```
　　忘れる　　  →　忘れ＋する
　　忘れる＋も　＝　忘れもする
```

Or:

```
　　忘れない　　  →　忘れ＋しない
　　忘れない＋は　＝　忘れはしない
```

Your example is a little more complicated for a couple reasons.  First of all, ある has a suppletive negative form.  Instead of saying あらない, people just say ない, almost like the <strike>あら</strike> has been deleted:

```
　　あらない　　  →　あり＋しない
　　あらない＋は　＝　ありはしない
```

Your example also contains a contraction.  The /w/ has dropped from /ri wa/, which turns it into /ri (y)a/, and this in turn can contract to /rya(a)/:

```
　　あらない　　  →　あり＋しない
　　あらない＋は　＝　ありはしない　→　ありゃしない
```

And the final /ai/ has been replaced with the colloquial pronunciation /ee/:

```
　　あらない　　  →　あり＋しない
　　あらない＋は　＝　ありはしない　→　ありゃしない　→　ありゃしねえ
```

This is a colloquial and emphatic negative form of ある.

Answer (score 3):

ありゃしない in the context means "doesn't exist". So the whole sentence means "This good price doesn't exist anywhere else in this world."

By the way, ありゃしない is a spoken form of ありはしない. It consists of ある(exists) + しない(deny).